# Does anyone know of a good string  comparison / checking tool?

Tags: similarity

I am looking for a good online string checking tool that will allow me to enter two long strings; and it will show me where any differences occur. It would also be nice if there is a tool that on input of a string showed you below each character an index, with escaped characters handled correctly so that /0 only takes up one space and not two.

Does anyone know of such a tool? It would greatly assist in string verification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of Levenshtein distance? It seems similar to what you're looking for, and the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) has some links to online implementations.

Comment: Something along those lines would be helpful, Atlhough I'm not seeing any links to online implementations in the Wiki article.

Comment: There's this, not sure how useful it will be to you though: http://www.miislita.com/searchito/levenshtein-edit-distance.html 
I also saw source code for an implementation, if that's viable.

Comment: That is definitely helpful, but I was hoping for one that outlined where the occurrences where, and possible index's?

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of techniques like simmetrics, or locality sensitive hashing. Also look at the difflib library of python http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

After realizing what I should be searching for... "diff tool", I got : 
http://www.quickdiff.com/